# Procedure faixa de Preço

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Estou tentando criar uma procedure que conforme a faixa de preço pega um campo diferente da tabela.

```
Create Procedure BuscaPreco
@preco decimal,
@faixa1 int,
@faixa2 int,
@faixa3 int,
@faixa1=100,
@faixa2=200,
@faixa3=300
Select 
case when @preco <@faixa1 then p.preco1
when @preco <@faixa2 and @preco >=@faixa1 then p.preco2
when @preco <@faixa3 and @preco >= @faixa2 then p.preco3
else p.preco4
end,
from produtos p

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure BuscaPreco, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure BuscaPreco, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

Comment: Erro de syntax deve ser a vírgula depois do end ....end, sem entrar em maiores méritos

Comment: O segundo erro foi corrigido.

Comment: Não trabalho com sql server mas uma pesquisa rápida diz que precisa do DECLARE e SET https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/assignment-operator-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está declarando mais de uma vez as mesmas variáveis ao invés de atribuir um valor default e também está sobrando uma "," depois do seu case.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BuscaPreco
    @preco DECIMAL,
    @faixa1 INT = 100,
    @faixa2 INT = 200,
    @faixa3 INT = 300
AS
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (@preco < @faixa1) THEN p.preco1
        WHEN (@preco < @faixa2 AND @preco >= @faixa1) THEN p.preco2
        WHEN (@preco < @faixa3 AND @preco >= @faixa2) THEN p.preco3
        ELSE p.preco4
    END
FROM produtos p
GO
```

Comment: Deu certo ! Muito obrigado!